# php check for directory on users computer

Tags: php, file, directory

Is it possible to check for a directory on a users computer without knowing the directory? I want to write a php program that allows me to look at my skype photos, but every computer has a different file directory, based on the account name on the computer. File Directory:

```
C:\Users\compUser\AppData\Roaming\skype\Pictures
```

I'm looking for a similar function where; if we were to make the run command on a windows pc, you can type `%appdata%\skype\pictures` and have the file directory pop up.

Comment: If you want to use the value of `%appdata%`, you can access it from `$_ENV['appdata']`. Dunno if that's what you need, though.

Comment: No you can't. Besides, the path would be relative to the server, not the user's computer. It works for you because the files are on your local server. Otherwise that would be a *ridiculous* privacy concern.

Comment: @Vince did you found the alternative to this question, What other way or language could be used to achieve this. Please will like to know. Thanks.

Comment: @divy3993 Haven't found anything, it was a small project for me, that I gave up on haha. I'm sure there is something, as nothing it impossible. :) Keep searching, friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server side language, it can only browse the files on it's own server.

Comment: so what is the alternative solution to this? I mean what other web language could be helpful doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to local user pc directory for security motivations, you can access only to server directory (where php run)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language, it can only browse the files on it's own server.
and you cannot access any file from computer to php server without input